# Motion History Image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, motion

I am working on a project about action recognition using motion history images in matlab. I am new to this field. I did background subtraction using frame differencing method to get images that have only the moving person. Now I want to compute MHI. I found the following code for MHI. I did not understand what is fg{1} and how to use it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
vid= VideoReader('PS7A1P1T1.avi');
n = vid.NumberOfFrames; 

fg = cell(1, n);

 for i = 1:n
      frame = read(vid,i); 
      frame = rgb2gray(frame);
      fg{i} = frame;
 end
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%background subtraction using frame differencing method 
thresh = 25;            
bg = fg{1};           % read in 1st frame as background frame 
% ----------------------- set frame size variables ----------------------- 
fr_size = size(bg);              
width = fr_size(2); 
height = fr_size(1); 
% --------------------- process frames ----------------------------------- 
for i = 2:n 

    fr = fg{i};       % read in frame 

    fr_diff = abs(double(fr) - double(bg));  % cast operands as double to avoid negative overflow 

    for j=1:width                 % if fr_diff > thresh pixel in foreground 
        for k=1:height 
            if ((fr_diff(k,j) > thresh)) 
                fg {i}(k,j) = fr(k,j); 
            else 
                fg {i}(k,j) = 0; 
            end 
        end 
    end 

    bg = fr; 

    imshow(fg{i}) 

end 

out = MHI(fg);
```

//----------------------------------------
    function MHI = MHI(fg)

```
% Initialize the output, MHI a.k.a. H(x,y,t,T)
MHI = fg;

% Define MHI parameter T
T = 15; % # of frames being considered; maximal value of MHI.

% Load the first frame
frame1 = fg{1};

% Get dimensions of the frames
[y_max x_max] = size(frame1);

% Compute H(x,y,1,T) (the first MHI)
MHI{1} = fg{1} .* T;

% Start global loop for each frame
for frameIndex = 2:length(fg)

    %Load current frame from image cell
    frame = fg{frameIndex};

    % Begin looping through each point
    for y = 1:y_max
        for x = 1:x_max
            if (frame(y,x) == 255)
                MHI{frameIndex}(y,x) = T;
            else
                if (MHI{frameIndex-1}(y,x) > 1)
                    MHI{frameIndex}(y,x) = MHI{frameIndex-1}(y,x) - 1;
                else
                    MHI{frameIndex}(y,x) = 0;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If I have helped, consider accepting my answer to let the community know you no longer need help. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fg{1}` is most likely the first frame of a grayscale video. Given your comments, you are using the `VideoReader` class to read in frames. As such, read in each frame individually, convert to grayscale then place on a cell in a cell array. When you're done, call the script.

Here's the code modified from your comments to suit this task:

```
vid = VideoReader('PS7A1P2T1.avi');
n = vid.NumberOfFrames; 

fg = cell(1, n);

for i = 1:n
   frame = read(vid,i); 
   frame = rgb2gray(frame);
   fg{i} = frame;
end
```

You can then call the MHI script:

```
out = MHI(fg);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am reading the video using the following code. I didn't use any matrix. It seems that I am doing it in a wrong way? 

 vid= VideoReader('PS7A1P2T1.avi');
 OutVideoDir = 'IMAGE SEQUENCES';
 mkdir(OutVideoDir);
 numFrames = vid.NumberOfFrames; 
 n=numFrames;
 
 for i = 1:n
 frames = read(vid,i); 
 frames = rgb2gray(frames);
 baseFileName = sprintf('%d.jpg', i); % e.g. "1.jpg"
 fullFileName = fullfile(OutVideoDir, baseFileName); 
 imwrite(frames, fullFileName);
 end

Comment: Yes you're using VideoReader. I wasn't aware that you used that interface. I'll modify my answer later to fix this. I'm not in front of a computer currently.

Comment: Ok, really thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: I am getting this error in background subtraction code:

Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Error in Action_Recognition (line 85)
                fg (k,j) = 0;

Comment: I am using the code in this link for background subtraction:
http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/sourcecode/math/765783/frame_difference/frame_difference.m__.htm

Comment: `fg` is a cell array of frames. I will have to investigate further because I don't know how you're using that code you've linked me. This is why you should put all the code you've tried. It prevents going back and forth like what we're doing.

Comment: Ok, but how can I put the whole code. It is a bit long, and here I can put only up till 600 char?

Comment: Edit your question. Don't put code in comments. In fact, that is discouraged.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I fixed it now, but when I run the code I got inaccurate results for background subtraction images, they should be binary images, but they are not. And one more thing, how can I display MHI image? I tried "imshow(out)" , but I am getting errors.

Comment: @HindFawzi the code you wrote for background subtraction does not store the images as binary, so I'm not sure what it is you want.  Also, the "MHI" image is a cell array.  You want to display each frame... something like `imshow(out{1},[]);` to display the first MHI image will work.  I can't begin to modify your background subtraction code because you say the output is binary yet the expected output is clearly `double`.

Comment: I need to have only the moving person in the image therefore I applied frame differencing method since it is simple and easy. Binary image is the result of frame differencing and should be black and white only not a gray scale image, right? Please correct me if I am wrong; as I said before I am new to this field.